# Android : How to add images in Tab Host

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new at android programming.
I have created a Tab Host in my activity. (Screenshot given below)
[image: Screenshot]

I want to add images in each tab of these tabs :

_Personal Data

_History

_Visits

How Can I do that?

Sorry for bad English...thanks.

> Here is my code in activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:paddingTop="55dp">

                <TabHost
                    android:id="@+id/tabHost"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TabWidget
                            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TabWidget>

                        <FrameLayout
                            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/PersonalData_Tab"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:orientation="vertical"
                                android:background="#FFFFFF">

                                <ImageView
                                    android:id="@+id/IMG_User"
                                    android:layout_width="105dp"
                                    android:layout_height="105dp"
                                    android:src="@drawable/img_user"
                                    android:clickable="true"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    style="@style/myImageView"
                                    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ET_RecordNumber"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:hint="Record Number"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:visibility="invisible"
                                    android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/ET_Name"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:hint="Your Name"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:paddingTop="20dp" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/ET_Age"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:hint="Your Age"
                                    android:inputType="date"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:paddingTop="25dp" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/ET_Job"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:hint="Your Job"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:paddingTop="30dp" />

                                <EditText
                                    android:id="@+id/ET_Address"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:hint="Your Address"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:paddingTop="33dp" />

                                <LinearLayout
                                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:background="#FFFFFF"
                                    android:paddingTop="10dp">

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/button_add"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                                        android:text="Save"
                                        android:background="#FF8000"
                                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                                    <Button
                                        android:id="@+id/BT_Clear"
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                                        android:text="Clear"
                                        android:background="#949494"
                                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />


                                    <Button
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                                        android:text="View All"
                                        android:id="@+id/button_viewAll"
                                        android:background="#FF8000"
                                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                                    <Button
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Export"
                                        android:id="@+id/button_export"
                                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                                        android:background="#949494"
                                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>


                                    <Button
                                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                        android:text="Delete"
                                        android:id="@+id/button_delete"
                                        android:layout_weight="1.0"
                                        android:background="#FF8000"
                                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

                                </LinearLayout>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/ET_IMGPath"
                                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                                    android:hint="IMG Path"
                                    android:ems="10"
                                    android:singleLine="true"
                                    android:visibility="invisible" />

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/History_Tab"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:text="This is tab 2"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                            </LinearLayout>

                            <LinearLayout
                                android:id="@+id/Visits_Tab"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                                android:orientation="vertical">

                                <TextView
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:text="This is tab 3"
                                    android:layout_gravity="center"/>

                            </LinearLayout>
                        </FrameLayout>
                    </LinearLayout>
                </TabHost>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Here is me code in MainActivity

TabHost host = (TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
        host.setup();

```
    //Personal Data Tab
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = host.newTabSpec("Personal Data");
    spec.setContent(R.id.PersonalData_Tab);
    spec.setIndicator("Personal Data");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //History Tab
    spec = host.newTabSpec("History");
    spec.setContent(R.id.History_Tab);
    spec.setIndicator("History");
    host.addTab(spec);

    //Visits Tab
    spec = host.newTabSpec("Visits");
    spec.setContent(R.id.Visits_Tab);
    spec.setIndicator("Visits");
    host.addTab(spec);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code from

<strike>spec.setIndicator("Personal Data")</strike>

to

```
spec.setIndicator("Personal Data", ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.yourdrawable));
```